# Pass Connection string variable in Crystal Report instead of pasing whole connection string in CrystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon()

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to pass connection string variable for making connection with Crystal Report instead of passing whole connection string in CrystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username","password").

Example:
//I want to do something like this

```
string con;
CrystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon(con);
```

//I don't want to pass string like

```
CrystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username","password").
```

Please Help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();    
doc.SetDatabaseLogon(AppConfig.ReportServerDSUserName, AppConfig.ReportServerDSPassword, AppConfig.ReportServerDomain, "TexERP", false);
```

You can pass the values for `SetDatbaseLogon` like this.
You have to store the values in the `AppConfig`.